# Create an ASCII thermometer using MessageFormat

Tags: java, ascii-art, messageformat

I am using Java's `MessageFormat` class to create a string that takes several condition statements as parameters using the `format` method. With it I have created a thermometer using ASCII characters which takes in a random number as celsius and depending on that number, inserts asterisk characters into the string at specific locations depending on a condition, e.g. `((celsius >= 25) ? "*" : " ")`. In other words, the asterisks represent the temperature level in a thermometer depending on the temperature value.

[image: ASCII thermometer]

At the moment I am using similar if statements in each of the 14 parameters which then determines if it should add an asterisk in said location `temp >= location` or an empty space `temp <= location`. I'm sure there is a much more efficient and cleaner way in doing this using another method, e.g. embedded for loop, regex, function, built-in method, etc.

Here's an example of the code (beware escape characters):

```java
// random value between -35 and 40
double celsius = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 - 35) - 35);

// ASCII Thermometer
String meter = MessageFormat.format(
                "     ______________________"
                + "\r\n     |   ^F     _    ^C   |"
                + "\r\n     |  100  - |{0}| -  40  |"
                + "\r\n     |   90  - |{1}| -  30  |"
                + "\r\n     |   80  - |{2}| -  25  |"
                + "\r\n     |   70  - |{3}| -  20  |"
                + "\r\n     |   60  - |{4}| -  15  |"
                + "\r\n     |   50  - |{5}| -  10  |"
                + "\r\n     |   40  - |{6}| -   5  |"
                + "\r\n     |   30  - |{7}| -   0  |"
                + "\r\n     |   20  - |{8}| -  -5  |"
                + "\r\n     |   10  - |{9}| - -10  |"
                + "\r\n     |    0  - |{10}| - -20  |"
                + "\r\n     |  -10  - |{11}| - -25  |"
                + "\r\n     |  -20  - |{12}| - -30  |"
                + "\r\n     |  -30  - |{13}| - -35  |"
                + "\r\n     |         '***`       |"
                + "\r\n     |       (*****)      |"
                + "\r\n     |        `---'        |"
                + "\r\n     |____________________|"
                + "\r\n\r\n",
        ((celsius >= 35) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 30) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 25) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 20) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 15) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 10) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 5) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= 0) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= -5) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= -10) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= -15) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= -20) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= -25) ? "*" : " "),
        ((celsius >= -30) ? "*" : " "));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want this?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // random value between -35 and 40
    double celsius = Math.round(Math.random() * (40 - 35) - 35);

    final String s = "     ______________________"
            + "\r\n     |   ^F     _    ^C   |"
            + "\r\n     |  100  - |{0}| -  40  |"
            + "\r\n     |   90  - |{1}| -  30  |"
            + "\r\n     |   80  - |{2}| -  25  |"
            + "\r\n     |   70  - |{3}| -  20  |"
            + "\r\n     |   60  - |{4}| -  15  |"
            + "\r\n     |   50  - |{5}| -  10  |"
            + "\r\n     |   40  - |{6}| -   5  |"
            + "\r\n     |   30  - |{7}| -   0  |"
            + "\r\n     |   20  - |{8}| -  -5  |"
            + "\r\n     |   10  - |{9}| - -10  |"
            + "\r\n     |    0  - |{10}| - -20  |"
            + "\r\n     |  -10  - |{11}| - -25  |"
            + "\r\n     |  -20  - |{12}| - -30  |"
            + "\r\n     |  -30  - |{13}| - -35  |"
            + "\r\n     |         '***`       |"
            + "\r\n     |       (*****)      |"
            + "\r\n     |        `---'        |"
            + "\r\n     |____________________|";

    final int[] celsiusDegreeCompare = new int[]{
            35, 30, 25, 20, 15, 10, 5, 0, -5, -10, -20, -25, -30, -35
    };

    final String[] parameters = new String[14];

    IntStream.range(0, parameters.length).forEach(i -> {
        parameters[i] = (celsius >= celsiusDegreeCompare[i]) ? "*" : " ";
    });

    // ASCII Thermometer
    String meter = MessageFormat.format(s, parameters);

    System.out.println("celsius: " + celsius);
    System.out.println(meter);
}
```

Result:

```
celsius: -31.0
     ______________________
     |   ^F     _    ^C   |
     |  100  - | | -  40  |
     |   90  - | | -  30  |
     |   80  - | | -  25  |
     |   70  - | | -  20  |
     |   60  - | | -  15  |
     |   50  - | | -  10  |
     |   40  - | | -   5  |
     |   30  - | | -   0  |
     |   20  - | | -  -5  |
     |   10  - | | - -10  |
     |    0  - | | - -20  |
     |  -10  - | | - -25  |
     |  -20  - | | - -30  |
     |  -30  - |*| - -35  |
     |         ***`       |
     |       (*****)      |
     |        `---        |
     |____________________|
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are trying to *draw an image* rather than printing a `String` i would advice you to create a class that is responsible for that, namely `AsciiImageThermometerPrinter`. That class would be able to `print()` a certain state of temperature.

To build your `String` i suggest to use `StringBuilder` rather than `MesssgeFormat`.

As for creating your output i would use an line-based middle part that draws line-by-line your thermometer, a part for the header and one for the bottom-part.

### what would be different?

You could simply provide thermometers with different ranges and units. you simply provide longer or shorter thermometers.

Your code would be testable and other developer would understand your code easier.

Your code would be more SOLID.

Comment: Sorry that answer was written from my mobile phone. Later, when im in the office i will provide some examples for the `StringBuilder` parts.